# SwiftLint rule to prefer the use of implicit self where it can be used?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

In SwiftLint there is a rule for `explicit_self` and a rule for `redundant_self_in_closure`.

But is there a rule would warn for overuse of `self`?

For instance in this example...

```
struct FooBar {
  let someValue: String

  func doSomething() {
    print(self.someValue)
  }
}
```

In this the `self.` should warn as it isn't preferred/required.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t believe so. For complete list of rules, run `swiftlint rules`. That will show you what rules are there, which require you to opt-in, etc.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I may have to put in a proposal for something like this. See if it’s popular enough.